# Reading XML data to StackPanel controls

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, binding, isolatedstorage

I want to load data from XML file which is in IsolatedStorage. Then I have in variable specific index number which is XML element index. And here I have a problem, because I want to load in TextBoxes (in normal StackPanel) values from this element. I tried with binding and putting this in listbox but then I cannot read text from this boxes, cause it's listbox items. Simply I want to load element attributes to TextBoxes and after it I want to read edited text in this textboxes.
This is example xml element:

```
<person index="1" att1="qwerty" att2="azerty" att3="abcdef"/>
```

This is Xaml code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stack">
 <TextBlock Height="27" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Record index:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF6C6C6C"/>
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Index}" x:Name="index_box_det" Height="65" Margin="-12,-10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF40AA2F" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="467" SelectionBackground="#FF40AA2F" SelectionForeground="White" BorderBrush="#FF3FA92E" FontSize="18.667"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I have tried this:

```
var ind = "1";
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("People2.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {
                XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("person")
                                   where c.Attribute("index").Value == ind
                                   select new Person()
                                   {
                                       index= c.Attribute("index").Value,
                                       att1= c.Attribute("att1").Value,
                                       att2= c.Attribute("att2").Value,
                                       att3= c.Attribute("att3").Value
                                   };
                stack.DataContext = filteredData;
            }
```

But as you think, it does not work. Somebody have idea to load this values to textboxes ?

EDIT:
I have tried this:

```
 var ind = "1";
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("People2.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {
                XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("person")
                                   where c.Attribute("index").Value == ind
                                   select new Person()
                                   {
                                       index= c.Attribute("index").Value,
                                       att1= c.Attribute("att1").Value,
                                       att2= c.Attribute("att2").Value,
                                       att3= c.Attribute("att3").Value
                                   };
                stack.DataContext = filteredData;
            }
```

index_box_det.Text = Index;

Still not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must invoke `FirstOrDefault` method:

```
var ind = "1";
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("People2.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
    {
        XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
        var filteredData = (from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("person")
           where c.Attribute("index").Value == ind
           select new Person()
           {
               Index = c.Attribute("index").Value,
               Att1 = c.Attribute("att1").Value,
               Att2 = c.Attribute("att2").Value,
               Att3 = c.Attribute("att3").Value
           }).FirstOrDefault();
        stack.DataContext = filteredData;
    }
}
```

`Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    string index;
    string att1;
    string att2;
    string att3;

    public string Index
    {
        get { return index; }
        set { index = value; }
    }

    public string Att1
    {
        get { return att1; }
        set { att1 = value; }
    }

    public string Att2
    {
        get { return att2; }
        set { att2 = value; }
    }

    public string Att3
    {
        get { return att3; }
        set { att3 = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i changed that, but it still not works. Compiler does not showing any errors but its still not showing any of values.

Comment: @ŁukaszWróblewski what did you changed?

Comment: == 1 to == "1". Tak naprawdę jak kopiowałem to przez nieuwage skasowałem nawiasy ;p

Comment: @ŁukaszWróblewski don't forget change "Index" to "index" in binding (first bug).

Comment: @ŁukaszWróblewski check my answer again.